# Ionic 2 : Programmatically restart app fail with internet test connection

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I have to build an Ionic 2 app with possibility to logout. So, when my user logout, I have to clear all component and come back to the login page. 
I use this method to do that :

```
initialHref = window.location.href;
logout() {
        navigator.splashscreen.show();
        window.location.assign(this.initialHref);
}
```

But I have a problem. I have to test user internet connection for some task in my app. I have a method to test that :

```
getInternetConnection() : string {
    let networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    let states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'unknown';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'ethernet';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'wifi';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = '2g';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = '3g';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = '4g';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'generic';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'not-connected';

    return states[networkState];
  }
```

The problem : When I use my logout method, my app stay in the splashscreen indefinitely. I have this error in Android Studio :

```
06-14 11:27:39.728 14192-14192/com.ionicframework.myapp722890 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(85505)] "ReferenceError: Connection is not defined
at PTools.getInternetConnexion (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:5999:16)
at PDataManager.isConnected (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:10648:40)
at new PDataManager (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:10367:14)
at AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:343:69)
at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:481:53)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:86063:44)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:154924:45)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:155352:49)
at ElementInjector.get (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:154428:27)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:154924:45)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:155352:49)
at ElementInjector.get (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:154428:27)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:154185:24)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:154120:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:153989:21)", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (85505)
```

I don't know what I have to do to resolve this problem. 
Maybe I can :
Find another method to logout ?
Find another method to test internet connection ?
I have to keep this two functionnality. 
When I use app for the first time, my internet connection test works well.

Any idea ?

Comment: First of all i think it would be better to use the native plugin 4 ionic 2 networks  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/

Comment: Wonderful ! It's so much better with this ! :) Thanks !

Comment: Your welcome, for most of the plugins, just go to the ionic native site you'll get the help you need there.